# serialize class object that contain secret data - serialization with encryption

Tags: c#, winforms, office-addins

I'm developing Add-In for office. In my application i need to store some data provided by the user.

Now these data 'll be shared among office programs(word, excel, power-point), So i need to store them in some file i can access from my application under any office program.

My question is how i can serialize my data objects(i got examples on that) but i want some data like passwords to be encrypted. I have tried to store the data objects into binary format but i still can read the data(just open it in notepad++).. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I don't need to know how to encrypt data, i want to serialize my data objects and in same time encrypt the important or secret data(serialization with encryption)

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501289/c-sharp-byte-encryption

Comment: can the object used to serialize my data Encrypt some fields ?

Comment: encrypt the whole lot, then decrypt it before deserializing.  Alternatively don't use plain text passwords ( bad idea anyways )

Comment: why don't you want to encrypt the whole lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing what you needed the following methods decorated with the correct attributes should work... you just need some custom code to run during and after serialization and then after deserialization...

```
// Save your password so you can reset it after the object has been serialized.
[NonSerialized()] 
private string SavedPassword;

// This saves the value of Password and Encrpts it so it will be stored Encrypted.
// I am leaving out the Encrypt code to make it cleaner here.
[OnSerializing()]
internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    SavedPassword = Password;
    Password = Encrypt(Password);
}

// reset the Password after serialization so you can continue to use your object.
[OnSerialized()]
internal void OnSerializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    Password = SavedPassword;
}

// On deserialize you need to Decrypt your Password.
[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    Password = Decrypt(Password);
}
```

Explanation of the attributes and methods...

[NonSerialized()] - tells the serializer to not include this field / property in the serialized object.

[OnSerializing()] - tells the serializer to call this method before serializing the object.  Our encryption code goes here because we want the encrypted value of the password to be serialized.

[OnSerialized()] - tells the serializer to call this method after the object has been serialized.  We need to reset the password to it's unencrypted state here.  (instead of saving the password unencrypted you could do a decrypt here just as easily)

[OnDeserialized()] - tells the serializer to call this method after the object has been deserialized.  This is where our decrypt goes because the object isn't ready to be used until we decrypt the password.

With these attributes and methods in place the Password property will automatically be encrypted during serialization and decrypted during deserialization.

Comment: i need to serialize my data and also encrypt some fields(serialization with encryption)

Comment: can you explain more your code or if it possible make a complete one with like username(plain-text) and password(encrypted)

Comment: It sounded like you had a plaintext Password stored in your object.  But it really doesn't matter what the type of the Password is just as long as you write your Encrypt and Decrypt to handle what you pass in and modify SavedPassword to be the same type as your Password.

Answer (score 0):

A: if you want to be lazy, just [GZip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) it - it compresses the data to make it so you can only read it by first un-GZiping it.

B: [Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) the data. This requires you have a password to read it. This is also harder to implement.

Feel free to ask for clarification on how to use either of these options.

Comment: i need to serialize my data and also encrypt some fields(serialization with encryption)